# What is the range of an element of an int array can have?

Tags: c

If I declare an array
  int A[40]
then 40 blocks of 4byte(32 bit system) memory will be created
then can all the elements of array range b/w -32000 to 32000

Comment: if you've got A[40], then `A[41]` is undefined and will cause problems, if I'm reading your "question" right.

Comment: Judging from your question, it seems you do not fully understand what an array means. It might be a good idea to read more about this.

Comment: What does "b/w" mean? Black-and-white? Better-or-worse?

Comment: @KerrekSB: from context, probably "bet-ween".

Comment: @Jongware: That wouldn't make sense: "between -32000 to 32000" doesn't parse...

Comment: @KerrekSB: it makes as much sense as the rest :/

Comment: @MarcB:  If you declare `int A[40];`, then element `A[40]` is out of range!  Valid indicies are `A[0]...A[39]`

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think there is a difference between an `int` element in an array, and a plain `int`? There isn't: it's the same type.

Each of the 40 integers in your array `A` will have the same range as any other variable of type `int`.

You should add `#include <limits.h>` and use the `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` macros.

For a 32-bit `int`, the range is much larger than -32000 to 32000, it's from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia:

> The signed range of integer values that can be stored in 32 bits is
>   -2147483648 through 2147483647 (unsigned: 0 through 4,294,967,295).

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
int A[40];
```

*Each* of the 40 elements of the array have have a range of *at least* -32,767 to 3,2767.  That is the *minimum* range on `int` per the C spec.

Since `int` on your machine is 32-bit, the range is expected to be -2,147,483,648 to -2,147,483,647.

32-bit `int` is common.  To determine the range for a given platforms

```
#include <limits.h>
printf("Min %d\n", INT_MIN);
printf("Max %d\n", INT_MAX);
```